# @FXML annotation and FXMLLoader class not resolved to a type in Java 11 and JavaFX 11

Tags: java, javafx, openjfx, javafx-11

Earlier my project used to be on Java 8 but now I am using Java 11 along with JavaFX 11 and now JavaFX has been decoupled from Java since Java 11. I haven't download the JavaFX SDK but added below dependency in pom.xml for getting required modules and jar files which were used to be part of Java itself in earlier versions.

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
        </dependency>
```

But I am getting compilation error `can not be resolved to a type` on `@FXML` annotation and `FXMLLoader` class.

Do I need to add some other/extra dependencies to resolve this issue?

Comment: @Jose Pereda Thanks for editing and adding correct tag

Comment: Try this https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx/11

Answer (score 16, accepted):

FXML (`@FXML`annotation, FXMLLoader...) were moved to the module `javafx.fxml` with the Java 9 release.

Before JavaFX 11, whenever you were calling something JavaFX related, you had all the javafx modules available within the SDK.

But now you have to include the ones you need:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
    <version>11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
    <version>11</version>
</dependency>
```

Note that `javafx.controls` depends on `javafx.graphics` and `java.base`, so you don't need to include those. And `javafx.fxml` directly depends on `javafx.base`.