# IntelliJ IDEA - Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-11

I'm running **IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2018.2.5** with **JDK 11.0.1** and **JavaFX 11 from OpenJFX**. I know it's a common error and I tried many of the proposed fixes but nothing works.

No matter which JavaFX project I try to run I get the error:

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

If I add the following to the VM options

```
 --module-path="C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls
```

I get these errors:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper (in unnamed module @0x5fce9dc5) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.util.Utils (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.util to unnamed module @0x5fce9dc5
    at com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper.<clinit>(FXMLLoaderHelper.java:38)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.<clinit>(FXMLLoader.java:2056)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:13)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application sample.Main
```

I tried reinstalling without any luck. I have also tried to change
`getClass().getResource(...)` to `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(...)` or to something like `Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/sample.fxml"));` but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There are similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603396/fxml-annotation-and-fxmlloader-class-not-resolved-to-a-type-in-java-11-and-java) or this other [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467561/intellij-cant-recognize-javafx-11-with-openjdk-11).

Before JavaFX 11, whenever you were calling something JavaFX related, you had all the javafx modules available within the SDK.

But now you have to include the modules/dependencies you need.

Your error says that you are using FXML but it can't be resolved, but you have just added the `javafx.controls` module:

```
--add-modules=javafx.controls
```

As you can see in the [JavaDoc](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/module-summary.html) the `javafx.controls` module depends on `javafx.graphics` and `java.base`, but none of those modules includes the FXML classes.

If you need FXML classes like the `FXMLLoader`, you need to include `javafx.fxml` module:

```
 --module-path="C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11\lib" \
    --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

The same will apply if you need media or webkit, those have their own [modules](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/).

Comment: If I am not completely wrong, you will have to replace the = with spaces

Comment: @AlexH. Both work, though space is preferred