# Understanding how the main class affects JPMS

Tags: java, javafx, java-11, java-platform-module-system, javafx-11

I have a very basic JavaFX application that works flawlessly if the Application class is **not** the Main class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(App.class, args);
    }

}

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(); // works
    }

}
```

However, when I merge the two together (which is the recommended way in most tutorials, including [OpenJFX's official documentation](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/blob/9244c1f2df35f6c1bdddbdc83b48da75af378481/HelloFX/Maven/hellofx/src/main/java/HelloFX.java)), the module system throws an `IllegalAccessError` (at least on OpenJDK 11.0.2):

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(); // throws IllegalAccessError
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(MainApp.class, args);
    }

}
```

The exception is:

> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class `com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper` (in unnamed module `@0x642c1a1b`) cannot access class `com.sun.javafx.util.Utils` (in module `javafx.graphics`) because module `javafx.graphics` does not export `com.sun.javafx.util` to unnamed module `@0x642c1a1b`

The weird thing is, that I *did not* actively use the module system. I did not add a `module-info.java` to my project. So I assumed everything should get exported to any unnamed modules? But that is not even the point.

The main question is: Why does the same code behave differently if distributed across two classes? In both cases `FXMLLoader` uses `com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper`, which in turn uses `com.sun.javafx.util.Utils`. So either I should get the exception in both cases or in none. What is the difference?

Comment: Seems strange. Please provide a real MCVE for this.

Comment: @flakes Just try and run the code. You can get the demo project [on GitHub](https://github.com/overheadhunter/so-question-54756176)

Comment: perfect that's what I wanted. Exact package names and build tools are going to be important when investigating this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few answers already posted that could apply partially to your questions, but it might be convenient to collect them here and present them in a full answer.

**Application class**

In the answer to [Maven Shade JavaFX runtime components are missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653836/maven-shade-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing/52654791#52654791) I explained the reason why, when you use the `Application` class as your main class, you are expected to use the module system.

In summary:

> As you can read [here](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2018-June/021977.html):
>
> This error comes from `sun.launcher.LauncherHelper` in the java.base module ([link](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/launcher/LauncherHelper.java#l995)).
>
> If the main app extends `Application` and has a `main` method, the `LauncherHelper` will check for the `javafx.graphics` module to be present as a named module:

```
Optional<Module> om = ModuleLayer.boot().findModule(JAVAFX_GRAPHICS_MODULE_NAME);
if (!om.isPresent()) {
    abort(null, "java.launcher.cls.error5");
}
```

> If that module is not present, the launch is aborted.

Every JavaFX 11 jar has a `module-info.class` file, so by definition, these are expected to be added to the module path.

But if you don't run via `Application` class, that check is not done.

**Main class**

This other answer to [Different behaviour between Maven & Eclipse to launch a JavaFX 11 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52741129/different-behaviour-between-maven-eclipse-to-launch-a-javafx-11-app/52743896#52743896)
 explains why it works without the modular system when you use a `Launcher` class (a Main class not extending Application) with the Maven `exec:java` plugin.

In summary:

- Using a Launcher is required to overcome the mentioned `sun.launcher.LauncherHelper` issue.
- Like the maven plugin runs in the classpath, loading all the dependencies into an isolated thread, so does IntelliJ in this case.

If you check the command line when you run `Main.main()`:

```
/path/to/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java \
    "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=60556:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin"  \
    -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8  \
    -classpath /path/to/so-question-54756176-master/target/classes:/path/to/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/11.0.2/javafx-base-11.0.2.jar:.../path/to/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-fxml/11.0.2/javafx-fxml-11.0.2-mac.jar  \
    Main
```

All the JavaFX jars from the JavaFX SDK are added to the classpath, and you are running the classic `java -cp ... Main`.

**javafx.fxml missing**

These other answer to [IntelliJ IDEA - Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52906773/intellij-idea-error-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing-and-are-required-t/52907749#52907749) explains the error you get when you run on the module system but you don't add `javafx.fxml` to the `--add-modules` option.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper (in unnamed module @0x5fce9dc5) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.util.Utils (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.util to unnamed module @0x5fce9dc5
    at com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper.<clinit>(FXMLLoaderHelper.java:38)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.<clinit>(FXMLLoader.java:2056)
```

Your error says that you are using FXML but it can't be resolved in the module-path, so it is trying to access via reflection and that fails since you didn't opened that `javafx.graphics` to your unnamed module.

So now you will ask: I didn't set the `javafx.graphics` in the first place!

Well, you didn't, but IntelliJ did it for you!

Check the command line when you run `MainApp.main()`:

```
/path/to/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java \
    --add-modules javafx.base,javafx.graphics \
    --add-reads javafx.base=ALL-UNNAMED \
    --add-reads javafx.graphics=ALL-UNNAMED \
    "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=60430:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin" \
    -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 \
    -classpath /path/to/so-question-54756176-master/target/classes:/path/to/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/11.0.2/javafx-base-11.0.2.jar:.../.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/11.0.2/javafx-graphics-11.0.2-mac.jar \
    MainApp
```

You can see that IntelliJ by default adds `javafx.base` and `javafx.graphics`. So only the `javafx.fxml` is missing (and then you should of course add the module-path).

The recommended solution, as you pointed out, is in the [docs](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Intellij):

Either on command line, using `--module-path` to include the path to your JavaFX SDK lib folder, and `--add-modules` to include `javafx.fxml` in this case (where you don't have controls).

[image: IntelliJ VM arguments]

Or using the Maven plugin. At some point you will have to leave your IDE, so you will need to use a plugin to run the application.

**Maven exec**

A final note on the Maven `exec` plugin, in case you use it:

What's more, the recommended Maven solution, until the plugin `exec:java` is fixed for the modular system (and the good news is that this is being [done](https://github.com/mojohaus/exec-maven-plugin/commit/dd95d38b7a25ff819701ee61321f7d23e3e8229a) *as we speak*), will be using `exec:exec` instead, as explained in this [issue](https://github.com/openjfx/openjfx-docs/issues/76), so you can specify both vm arguments.

Comment: Wow, thanks for this in-depth answer! really appreciate all the details. Also it shows how much I dont know about those libraries yet. So when leaving the IDE and distributing the application, I need to add the ˋ—add-modulesˋ option for javafx despite the fact I am not using the JPMS myself, right?

Comment: You can still use a launcher class and the current `exec:java` plugin, but that's going to change really soon, and there won't be another alternative, so you will have to use the modular system, whether you like it or not...